# Size of a filtered dimension in Crossfilter?

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

I've read through the Crossfilter API docs several times but can't see how to do the following.

Suppose I have set up

```
crossfilter(event);
```

and a dimension foo:

```
var foo = event.dimension(function(d) { return d.foo; }),
foos = foo.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d) ; });
```

Then, before any filters are applied, `event.size()` will give me the number of records in the event, and `foos.size()`  will give me the number of distinct records in the foo dimension

Great! Now I apply some filters by sliding brushes around. `event.groupAll().value()` now gives me the current number of records in event that are selected. Great again.

Now how do I get the current number of distinct records in the foo dimension? I've tried many different combinations of the API primitives, but none seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

This should do the trick

```
var n = foo.top(Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment the solution proposed by Reno.

> This should do the trick
>
> `var n = foo.top(Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY).length;`

The problem of this solution is that is not efficient, because top function is ordering the data.

I have the same problem that you and I have a counter in the filter to know how many entries have the dimension.

Comment: crossfilter always keeps a sorted index of the data, that's how it applies the filters/groups efficiently, so `top` and `bottom` do not apply a sort, but they will have to loop through all the data once, so you still get a O(n) operation instead of an O(1).